# SQL query not functioning as required

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this database of college. I have to Retrieve student-ids of students who have taken a class with an instructor named “John”.

SO far

```
SELECT student_id
FROM enrolls
JOIN teaches ON enrolls.number=teaches.number
WHERE Instructor.name=(
    SELECT name 
    FROM Instructor 
    WHERE name='john'
);
```

but this is not working.

```
create table Course (
  number int,
  title varchar(255),
  credits int,
  syllabus varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (number)
  );

INSERT INTO Course VALUES (620,'Algorithm',3,'XYZ');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (232,'Java',2,'ABC');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (420,'Cpp',2,'PQRS');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (720,'Big Data',3,'NVGY');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (120,'Intelligent System',4,'KJHU');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (220,'Operating System',3,'GED');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (480,'Graphics',4,'RSFN');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (520,'Distributed Networks',3,'NHU');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (820,'Data Mining',3,'TYU');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (700,'Cryptography',1,'MNO');

create table Student (
  student_id int,
  name varchar(255),
  department varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (student_id)
  );

INSERT INTO Student VALUES (2345,'Mike','Computer Science');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (346,'Rob','Computer Science');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (789,'Nick','Game Design');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (675,'Sara','Computer Science');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (123,'Raj','Mechanical');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (5331,'Jack','Biotech');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (1023,'Michelle','Chemical');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (9800,'Jie','Industrial');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (7834,'Dan','Petroleum');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (4567,'Patrick','Computer Science');


create table Instructor (
  instructor_id int,
  name varchar(255),
  department varchar(255),
  title varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (instructor_id)
  );

INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (12,'John','Computer Science','Java');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (23,'Bischof','Mechanical','Drawing');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (56,'Kwon','Biotech','Biology');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (78,'Deever','Security','Cryptography');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (45,'Jin','Computer Science','Cpp');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (67,'Bailey','Petroleum','Metalurgy');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (90,'Richard','Industrial','Manufacture');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (11,'Joe','Chemical','Chemistry');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (24,'Roger','Game Design','Cpp');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (55,'Zack','Industria','Design');


create table CourseOffering (
  number int,
  year int,
  semester int,
  section_number int,
  classroom int,
  PRIMARY KEY (number,year,semester,section_number),
  FOREIGN KEY (number) REFERENCES Course (number)
  );

INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (620,2012,2,102,3540);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (232,2011,1,103,3455);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (420,2013,3,101,2650);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (720,2013,3,100,3455);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (120,2014,1,102,3000);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (220,2008,2,104,1450);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (480,2009,4,106,1400);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (520,2010,3,102,3500);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (820,2008,3,100,2700);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (700,2012,1,103,2540);

create table CourseOffering_Timing (
  number int,
  year int,
  semester int,
  section_number int,
  timing int,
  PRIMARY KEY (number,year,semester,section_number,timing),
  FOREIGN KEY (number) REFERENCES Course (number)
  );

INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (620,2012,2,102,9);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (232,2011,1,103,3);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (420,2013,3,101,2);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (720,2013,3,100,5);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (120,2014,1,102,4);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (220,2008,2,104,10);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (480,2009,4,106,12);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (520,2010,3,102,4);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (820,2008,3,100,2);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (700,2012,1,103,3);

create table PreRequisite (
  number int,
  prerequisite_number int,
  PRIMARY KEY (number,prerequisite_number),
  FOREIGN KEY (number) REFERENCES Course(number)
  );

INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (620,480);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (232,120);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (420,320);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (720,580);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (120,110);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (220,130);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (480,380);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (520,360);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (820,700);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (700,610);


create table enrolls (
  student_id int,
  number int,
  year int,
  semester int,
  section_number int,
  grade varchar(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (student_id,number,year,semester,section_number),
  FOREIGN KEY (number,year,semester,section_number) REFERENCES CourseOffering(number,year,semester,section_number),
  FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES Student (student_id)  
  );

INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (2345,620,2012,2,102,'A');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (346,232,2011,1,103,'B');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (789,420,2013,3,101,'A');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (675,720,2013,3,100,'C');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (123,120,2014,1,102,'B');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (5331,220,2008,2,104,'A');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (1023,480,2009,4,106,'B');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (9800,520,2010,3,102,'A');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (7834,820,2008,3,100,'C');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (4567,700,2012,1,103,'F');

create table teaches (
  instructor_id int,
  number int,
  year int,
  semester int,
  section_number int,
  PRIMARY KEY (instructor_id, number, year, semester, section_number),
  FOREIGN KEY (instructor_id) REFERENCES Instructor(instructor_id),
  FOREIGN KEY ( number, year, semester, section_number) REFERENCES CourseOffering( number, year, semester, section_number)
  );


INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (12,620,2012,2,102);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (23,232,2011,1,103);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (56,420,2013,3,101);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (78,720,2013,3,100);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (45,120,2014,1,102);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (67,220,2008,2,104);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (90,480,2009,4,106);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (11,520,2010,3,102);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (24,820,2008,3,100);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (55,700,2012,1,103);
```

Comment: What would the desired result set look like?

Answer (score 0):

Your WHERE clause needs to refer to one of the tables you have selected or joined, which are `enrolls` and `teaches`. So you would have to do something like `WHERE teaches.instructor_id=(SELECT instructor_id FROM Instructor WHERE name='john');`

PS: You might also want to throw a DISTINCT in your top level select.

Answer (score 0):

As your table schema is normalized you need to get the instructor_id instead of name to get the expected result:

```
SELECT
    enr.student_id
FROM
   enrolls enr JOIN teaches tea ON enr.number = tea.number
WHERE
    tea.instructor_id = (
        SELECT instructor_id FROM Instructor WHERE name='john'
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to rewrite your query. I may have misinterpreted it but here it is:

```
SELECT e.student_id
FROM enrolls e
INNER JOIN teaches f ON e.number=f.number
INNER JOIN Instructor g ON f.instructor_id=g.instructor_id
WHERE g.name='John'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3181c/3/0

Answer (score 0):

Try below query As there are cases when students were not enroll for particular course for such scenario instructor hasn't teaches them.

```
select students.name from teaches
inner join instructor on teaches.instructor_id= instructor.instructor_id
inner join enrolls on enrolls.number= teaches.number and enrolls.year= teaches.year
and enrolls.semester= teaches.semester and enrolls.section_number= teaches.section_number
inner join students on students.student_id= enrolls.student_id where   instructor.name='John';
```